# How to assign a color to the rest of the values in scale_color_manual?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So this is the way that I'm setting up my own color pallette:

```
nice_colors <- c('orange', 'red', 'blue')
names(nice_colors) <- c("4", "2", "3")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color = factor(carb))) +
  geom_point() + scale_colour_manual(values = nice_colors, name = 'carb')+theme_bw()
```

mtcars$carb has 6 unique factors. I'm only assigning three of those factors so the rest of the factors are in grey. I want to assign the rest as green without explicitly telling it or it showing in my legend or changing the variable values.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `na.value` to green.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color = factor(carb))) +
  geom_point() + scale_colour_manual(values = nice_colors, name = 'carb', na.value = "green")+theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I though na.values is just for 'NA' values. That is not the case?

Comment: In `scale_colour_manual`, the 'NA' values don't represent true NAs otherwise the points would not be displayed. Instead, `na.values` captures the data that are not classified by the values param. In your example, you classified 2:4 with a named vector so any carb not in 2:4 is considered NA and is given a green color. If you enter `?scale_colour_manual` you'll see that grey50 is the default value.